# Evaluating command inside bash script leads to increment in $SHLVL

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have the following bash script (myscript.sh):

```
#!/bin/bash
$(echo $0)
```

Now: before sourcing myscript.sh, $SHLVL is 2. After sourcing it, is 3. Why?
Shouldn't the command evaluation exit after echo?

Thank you!

Comment: Your question is unclear.  How are you calling your script?  Please show the  command you are using to invoke the script so we can see the input and the output.

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of your script?  `$0` is the command that launched the script.  Putting that command inside `$()` causes the command to be executed, which would result in infinite recursion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you source a script in `bash`, `$0` expands to `bash` (or at least, the name of the shell `bash` was started as). So `$(echo $0)` expands first to `$(echo bash)`, which evaluates to `bash`, which is then identified as the name of the command to run, so a new shell instance is started. You can observe the nesting by running

```
echo foo; source myscript.sh; echo bar
```

First you'll see the string `foo` printed, then you'll be at a prompt in the new shell. Type `exit` to exit it, and you'll then see `bar` printed as your original command list finally completes.